# JQuery .on('click') is not working with KTDatatable each row edit dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, metronic

```
Hi I am facing some issue with KTDatatable dropdown edit for each row, datatable.on(‘click’, is not picking my click event, please help.
The click event is from bootstrap dropdown,
```

My code is as follows 
               //Datatable code
            var KTDatatableRecordSelectionDemo = function() {
           //.....
           //.....
           columns: [{
            },
           //.....
           {
                        field: 'Actions',
                        title: 'Actions',
                        template: function(row) {
                            return '\\\\\\ Organization Details\class="dropdown-item" href="#"> Location and contact detials\ Tax settings and bank details\ Access rights\class="dropdown-item" href="#" id="one_another"> Profile image and print logo\\\';},}]

```
        and here below the init datatable function



        var localSelectorDemo = function() {
        var datatable = $('#organizations').KTDatatable(options);
        //....
        //....
        datatable.on('click', '#form_organisation_details', function() {
            var dataId = $(this).attr("data-id");
            console.log(dataId);
        }

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 3):

you can't use onClick directly because the table was not initialized instead use something like this to add the click event after the table is loaded.

```
$(table_id).on('click', '.btn-edit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
            $.ajax({
                type: 'get',
                url: 'some link here',
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#response").html(data);
                },
            });
    });
```

and in the table itself use something like this to add the button in the table row

```
return Datatables::of($data)->addColumn('actions',function($row){
                return '<a title="Edit" class="btn-edit"><i class="la la-edit"></i></a>';
            })->rawColumns(['actions'])->make(true);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try to remove dompurify from the build.json config assets. This plugin sanitizes the datatable custom HTML template option.